# R JSON UTF-8 parsing

Tags: json, r, unicode, utf-8

I have an issue when trying to parse a JSON file in russian alphabet in R. The file looks like this:

```
[{"text": "Валера!", "type": "status"}, {"text": "когда выйдет", "type": "status"}, {"text": "КАК ДЕЛА?!)", "type": "status"}]
```

and it is saved in UTF-8 encoding. I tried libraries rjson, RJSONIO and jsonlite to parse it, but it doesn't work:

```
library(jsonlite)
allFiles <- fromJSON(txt="ru_json_example_short.txt")
```

gives me error

```
Error in feed_push_parser(buf) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       ď»ż[{"text": "Đ’Đ°Đ»ĐµŃ€Đ°!", "
                     (right here) ------^
```

When I save the file in ANSI encodieng, it works OK, but then, the Russian alphabet transforms into question marks, so the output is unusable.
Does anyone know how to parse such JSON file in R, please?

**Edit:** Above mentioned applies for UTF-8 file saved in Windows Notepad. When I save it in PSPad and the parse it, the result looks like this:

```
    text   type
1                                         <U+0412><U+0430><U+043B><U+0435><U+0440><U+0430>! status
2 <U+043A><U+043E><U+0433><U+0434><U+0430> <U+0432><U+044B><U+0439><U+0434><U+0435><U+0442> status
3                              <U+041A><U+0410><U+041A> <U+0414><U+0415><U+041B><U+0410>?!) status
```

Comment: Are you on windows? Are you 100% sure the file is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows. I saved the file as UTF-8 in Notepad.

Comment: in R, I tried `x<-'[{"text": "Валера!", "type": "status"}, {"text": "когда выйдет", "type": "status"}, {"text": "КАК ДЕЛА?!)", "type": "status"}]'` and verfied that `Encoding(x)=="UTF-8"`. Then i wrote it out with `writeLines(x, "test.txt", useBytes=TRUE)` and read it in with `fromJSON(txt="test.txt")` without a problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works for me, but the the result is in the edited questions - instead of the russian letters, there are only their codes, which is also pretty as I want to work with the text and see what's written there...

Comment: If you ran `x<-fromJSON(...)`, then what does `x$test` look like and what does `Encoding(x$text)` return?

Comment: It looks fine: > y$text
[1] "Валера!"      "когда выйдет" "КАК ДЕЛА?!)" 
> Encoding(y$text)
[1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
So thank you a lot! So when I want to see the russian text, I have to look at the specific column (i.e. $text in this example), right?

Comment: So it only looks funny when you do just `print(y)`? What version of R are you running?

Comment: R x64 3.1.2 with RStudio 0.98.1091

Comment: ...update to newest versions also didn't help...

Comment: I actually don't use windows myself. It works fine on my mac. I did some quick tests and it looks like that while ` y$text ` prints fine, `format( y$text )` causes a conversion to "native locale" encoding on windows which is what basically gets called when you print the data.frame object. I'm not sure how to force that to UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
dat <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]",
                paste(readLines("./ru_json_example_short.txt"),
                collapse=",")))
dat
[[1]]
       text   type
1      Валера! status
2 когда выйдет status
3  КАК ДЕЛА?!) status
```

ref: [Error parsing JSON file with the jsonlite package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package)