# Extract texts from a large character string based a pattern

Tags: regex, r, string, pattern-matching, strsplit

I have a large string of characters and would like to extract certain information from it matching pattern:

`str(input)
 chr [1:109094] "{'asin': '0981850006', 'description': 'Steven Raichlen\'s Best of Barbecue Primal Grill DVD. The first three volumes of the si"| truncated ...`

I get the following content of `input[1]` - description of product meta

```
[1] ("{'asin': '144072007X', 'related': {'also_viewed': ['B008WC0X0A', 'B000CPMOVG', 'B0046641AE', 'B00J150GAO', 'B00005AMCG', 'B005WGX97I'], 
         'bought_together': ['B000H85WSA']}, 
         'title': 'Sand Shark Margare Maron Audio CD', 
         'price': 577.15, 
         'salesRank': {'Patio, Lawn & Garden': 188289}, 
         'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31B9X0S6dqL._SX300_.jpg', 
         'brand': 'Tesoro', 
         'categories': [['Patio, Lawn & Garden', 'Lawn Mowers & Outdoor Power Tools', 'Metal Detectors']], 
'description': \"The Tesoro Sand Shark metal combines time-proven PI circuits with the latest digital technology creating the first.\"}")
```

Now I would like to iterate over each element of the large string and extract `asin`, `title`, `price`, `salesRank`, `brand` and `categories` that should be saved in a data.frame for better handling.

The data is originally from a JSON file as you might notice. I tried to import it using `stream_in` command, but it didn't help. So just imported it using `readLines`. Please please help! Being a bit desperate...Any hint is appreciated!

The `jsonlite` package shows the following problem:

```
lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      {'asin': '0981850006', 'descript
                     (right here) ------^
closing fileconnectionoldClass input connection.
```

**Any new ideas on that?**
Given lots of unanswered questions on that issue, must be very relevant for newbies ;)

Comment: Have you considered using `jsonlite` package?

Comment: yep :) and experience the problem similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158366/import-json-file-in-r-and-further-process-it-as-table?lq=1

Comment: But none of the suggestions there really helps...:(

Comment: I have the same problem with parsing JSON in JavaScript. JSON requires `"`, `'` are not allowed. That is why you are getting your invalid character error, use `"` instead.

Comment: Hi, Druzion. Thanks for you comment. Can you please be more specific - how should I specify the command?

Comment: Your JSON test is not valid. all keys should be wrapped with `"` double quotes instead of single quote. Once you fix JSON content, jsonlite will happily parse it

Comment: Hi Saleem, thanks! how can I achieve it in r while importing the file?

Comment: `the_fct <- function(what) gsub(sprintf('\'%s\'\\:\\s*(.*?),\\s*\'\\w+\'\\:|.', what), '\\1', gsub('\\n', '', input[1]), perl = TRUE); what <- c('asin', 'title', 'price', 'salesRank', 'brand' , 'categories'); lapply(what, the_fct)`

Comment: Hi rawr, seems to work for extracting content from char. Thanks!