# JSON parsing error, invalid character

Tags: json, r, parsing

I am using `fromJSON` from the `jsonlite` package in `[R]` to call `GetPlayerSummaries` from the Steam API (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) to get access to a user's data. For most calls it's working fine, but at some point I get an error:

```
    Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  lexical error: invalid bytes in UTF8 string.
          publicâ„¢ II: The Sith Lordsâ",               "gameid": "208580"          },
                     (right here) ------^
```

When I access the call in my browser I find a � on the spot where it is probably giving the error. I could Try-Catch but I'd really like to get this data. How to get around this?

Comment: Could you copypaste some example data on pastebin or so?

Comment: I suspect this is the part that is acting up, at one of the bottom lines http://pastebin.com/DesK5dyr

Comment: Actually your example json only fails because there is a trailing comma at the end that should not be there.

Comment: You are probably right, I changed the question to include the full error as given by [R]. So it's not the unknown character that's acting up, but the comma, if so, I'm not sure how to solve this with some code. I'm also not sure why it gives the error, some other lines (e.g., 'timecreated') also end with a comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error parsing JSON file with the jsonlite package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package)

Answer (score 2):

For my purpose, reading with `readLines` and then parsing it seemed to work

```
readlines <- readLines(link, warn = FALSE)
parse <- fromJSON(readlines)
```

I have no idea why and how this works, and may hence be not the most clean solution, but it seems to be robust for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use use jsonlite's streaming function

```
 json_file <- stream_in(file("abc.json"))
```

It has been answered in Stack Overflow here:

[Error parsing JSON file with the jsonlite package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package)

and here:

[Export JSON from Spark and input into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643178/export-json-from-spark-and-input-into-r)