# Export JSON from Spark and input into R

Tags: json, r, apache-spark

I've written some data from Spark to a JSON file and I am struggling to import it into R.

I cannot import it with any of the traditional JSON packages in R:

```
library("jsonlite")
bids <- fromJSON("win_rate_sample.json")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
 parse error: trailing garbage 
      X","domain":"ifunny_premium"}{"win":0,"bid_price":0.75,"size
                 (right here) ------^
```

How can I get this file into R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error parsing JSON file with the jsonlite package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Spark exports streaming json files like those discussed in the following question: [Error parsing JSON file with the jsonlite package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package)

The solution is to use jsonlite's streaming function:

```
library(jsonlite)
json_file <- stream_in(file("win_rate_sample.json"))
```