# fromJSON encoding issue

Tags: json, r, encoding, jsonlite

I try to convert a json object to R dataframe, here is the json object:

```
json <-
    '[
{"Name" : "a", "Age" : 32, "Occupation" : "凡达"}, 
{"Name" : "b", "Age" : 21, "Occupation" : "打蜡设计费"},
{"Name" : "c", "Age" : 20, "Occupation" : "的拉斯克奖飞"}
]'
```

then I use fromJSON, `mydf <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)`, the result is

```
  Name Age                                       Occupation
1    a  32                                 <U+51E1><U+8FBE>
2    b  21         <U+6253><U+8721><U+8BBE><U+8BA1><U+8D39>
3    c  20 <U+7684><U+62C9><U+65AF><U+514B><U+5956><U+98DE>
```

I was wondering how this happens, and is there any solution?

Using the package `rjson` can solve the problem, but the output is a list, but I want a dataframe output.

Thank you.

I've tried `Sys.setlocale(locale = "Chinese")`, well the characters are indeed Chinese,but the results are still weird like below:

`Name Age   Occupation
1    a  32         ·²´ï
2    b  21   ´òÀ¯Éè¼Æ·Ñ
3    c  20 µÄÀ­Ë¹¿Ë½±·É`

Comment: Related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package)

Comment: Those symbols in the output dataframe *are* an accurate representation of your inputs, they are simply printed that way in unicode. This has little to do with `fromJSON`. For instance, you can see the characters properly if you do `mydf$Occupation`. What are you using this for?

Comment: Your code produces the data frame with the correct characters in the `Occupation` column for me. What are you using to run R, RGUI, RStudio? Also, what's in `Sys.getlocale()` ?

Comment: @Chrisss That's right! So when I'm actually using the dataframe, that's OK, the problem only exists when the dataframe is printed? But in my case, I need to see the printed results to proceed the next step,

Comment: Why do you need to see the printed results? Sorry, if I'm asking more than answering, but this is simply how characters are encoded. You can even do `str(json)` and see that even in your raw string input, such encoding exists. Remember, you can still *use* the chinese characters. For example `mydf[mydf$Occupation == "的拉斯克奖飞", ]`

Comment: @Chrisss, In the first stage, I have to see the name, age and occupation at the same time. In this stage, it's only a look at the output, then start the second stage. So if I only do `mydf$Occupation` I can see the Chinese characters, but I won't know the corresponding name and age.

Comment: I see. Then `print(as.matrix(mydf))` should do just fine in the interim.

Comment: @Chrisss Well, it seems I've to use this as a solution, thanks~