# Importing json with jsonlite results in error

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I'm simply trying to read a file.json with the read_json() function from the jsonlite package.

I get this error:

```
mydata <- read_json(path="file.json",simplifyVector = TRUE)
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
          custom_questions_json": "" } {   "id": 15730670,   "lodged_a
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: post the json file. It seems it's not valid!

Comment: @codeteq I really can't. It has private info.

Comment: then remove all whitespace from the json. not within the content of course.

Comment: @EvanKnowles just logs. I think the problem could be that the type of info stored varies type and structure.

Comment: @codeteq how can I do this in R please?

Comment: I refer you to a post on SO, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package/26522000